# Color settings in Windows 10 are reset after locking PC

Tags: windows-10, colors

After adjusting key Window to `160 160 160 (gray color)` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors` and restarting PC everything is OK.

Background of all windows (e.g. in word or outlook) are gray. Up until I press `WIN + L` to lock PC. When I do that and sign back to PC, these settings are not active anymore. The value is still 160 160 160 but all backgrounds are white. I have to restart PC and everything is OK up until I press WIN + L...

Sync of the windows settings is disabled.
My PC is part of the LAN network domain. But this happens even if I disconnect my PC from network so any group policy (or something like this) should not be culprit.

I appreciate any help you can provide to prevent this from happening.

Comment: And what is about HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors? BTW, why do you want to change the Windows color by registry? It is very dangerous and not recommended!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I did exactly that (changed the Windows color by registry). But the settings are not permanent in the way I described above.

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. First, there are 2 Keys to change in the registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors. Seconds, why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: I do not insist on this way. I am opened to suggestions. I (my eyes) just need to get rid of white background color permanently.

Comment: You need to look around, there are different tutorials how to change the color settings, e.g. https://www.teachucomp.com/change-the-color-settings-in-windows-10-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you. I was not able to accomplish that all windows backgrounds are gray though. I am able to accomplish this only by changing registry setting I described above. But it is not permanent :-( Any other idea?

Comment: I have found an alternative that allows me to lock screen without colors settings being reset: https://fspro.net/lock-pc/

Comment: But I still prefer built-in solution...

Comment: Confirming this is a bug in all versions of Win8.1 - Win10. Locking the PC resets all Theme-defined colors. Have not tested Win7 or Win11.

Answer (score 1):

For full control of the Windows UI you will need 3rd party software like WindowBlinds:

https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/

**Key Features**

- Apply custom skins to your desktop
- Add backgrounds, textures and colors to skins
- Choose your own skin fonts
- Design your own skins with SkinStudio

Comment: As an open source alternative there's also https://github.com/namazso/SecureUxTheme. I am trying it now and it seems it's working good.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps make changes to your registry settings.
(Export the settings, as a backup, before making changes.)

1. Set your default color scheme for the following registry settings
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Windows`
2. Set the registry settings
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\DefaultColors\Standard\Window`

Note: the value is hexadecimal you can use this site to get the RGB --> Hex value
https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

Reboot and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm, after unlocking your system, Windows 8.1 and 10 reverts back to using default system colors instead of your theme-defined colors and/or colors defined in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`. Haven't tested Win7 or Win11.

The fix is to delete some registry properties found in:

`[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\DefaultColors]`

Basically just delete all properties except for `Default` found in these two keys:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\DefaultColors\HighContrast]
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\DefaultColors\Standard]
```

You could also probably just redefine the properties to match those found in your theme, but I haven't tested this.

[Source](https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/sign-out-restart-power-off-background-color-change-blue-flash-on-lock-screen.22641/post-121001)